# How to share wakatime goal into github readme

Tags: api, github, readme, wakatime

I want to share my wakatime goals into GitHub README.

I tried to find other GitHub profile that share their templates, but i did not find any goal stats.

Do I need to create myself if there isn't any?
And how?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [`athul/waka-readme`](https://github.com/athul/waka-readme)

> ### Dev Metrics in Readme

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8397274/87243943-e6b45c00-c457-11ea-94c9-2aa0bf241be8.png]

You might need to fork that repository, and modify [`main.py`](https://github.com/athul/waka-readme/blob/b317bba454ce1f0bacbcd7cdd3bfa6355f8fa4d1/main.py) in order to add Goals:

- listing your goals: [`GET /api/v1/users/:user/goals`](https://wakatime.com/developers#goals)
- reading a goal: [`GET /api/v1/users/:user/goals/:goal`](https://wakatime.com/developers#goal)

Comment: actually i already know that github but that doesnt show my "Goal" only how much time i spent with that language in a week . but my goal is everyday not a week. Like my image i upload in question

Comment: @AlfinIndrawan OK, from your question, it was not clear you already tried that particular repository.

Comment: @AlfinIndrawan I have edited the answer to suggest a course of action.