# Is there any way to collect stats for Google Colab with Wakatime?

Tags: github, statistics, google-colaboratory, wakatime

Do you know any ways to observe stats with Waka time while using Google Collab? You can also write about any other apps, that can help with this aim. The final goal is to add a widget in my Github profile file.
Thank you!

Comment: Is this similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72024167/6309?